# segment fault occurs when using c++11 standard thread library

Tags: c++, multithreading

My program crashed and I got following message.

```
segfault at 10 ip 00007f5a87e1ccd1 sp 00007f5a837d0bd8 error 4 in libpthread-2.17.so[7f5a87e13000+17000]
```

Then I checked the position where it occurred, and it shows that the problem may occur in pthread_mutex_destroy.

```
[root@stock-1 tmp]# addr2line -e /lib64/libpthread.so.0 -f 0x9CD1
__GI___pthread_mutex_destroy
:?
```

As it's the first time I encounter this problem, and I failed to reproduce it in my developing environment, these are all the information I can get.

In this program, there is a main thread and multiple worker threads. Main thread creates worker thread and wait for worker thread to send it a message. Worker thread finishes its task and send main thread a message.

The code is as follow.

```
#ifndef MESSAGEQUEUE_H_
#define MESSAGEQUEUE_H_

#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <queue>

struct CopyResult
{
    std::string mediaFile;
    std::string type;
    std::string status;
    long long size;
    int totalFileNumber = 0;
    int errorType = 0;
    std::string errorMessage;
};

template <class T>
class MessageQueue
{
public:
    T receive()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(_mutex);
        _condtion.wait(uLock,[this]{return !_messages.empty();});
        T msg = std::move(_messages.front());
        _messages.pop_front();
        return msg;
    }

    void send(T &&msg)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> uLock(_mutex);
        _messages.push_back(std::move(msg));
        _condtion.notify_one();
    }
private:
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condtion;
    std::deque<T> _messages;
};

#endif
```

main thread

```
CopyResult result = queue_->receive();
```

worker thread

```
queue->send(std::move(result));
```

I can't figure out what's the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I guess it's because the `MessageQueue` member function is still called after destructuring, adding a mutex lock before all `queue` pointer operations should fix the problem.

Comment: Just a guess - don't you forget to ```join()``` worker thread? Hard to inspect code when it's not a minimal reproducable example

Comment: To me, there seems nothing wrong with the code you presented. As others already suggested: check the lifetime of your threads and see if you can present more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my guess here without **[minimal  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** is:

You forgot to call (lets assume worker thread is called `worker_thread`):

```
if (worker_thread.joinable())
{
    worker_thread.join();
}
```

... which leads to error when mutex is already destroyed **outside** of worker_thread, but you try to lock this already destroyed mutex **inside** the worker_thread.
That guess made on your segfault - it's mutex destruction.

***P.S. Also let me suggest you run your program in debug build under GDB or similar debugger which is really usefull. It has ability to show you stack trace which may help to detect where you segfaulted and why.***